# Can't delete child element with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone please help me with my problem? I searched on the internet a lot. But still can't solve it.

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code-first with Microsoft SQL Server.

My entities are like this:

```
public class StockInfo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Key]
    public int StockInfoID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StockInfoID")]
    public virtual CompanyInfo companyInfo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StockInfo_ID")]
    public virtual List<CorpAction> corpActions { get; set; }
    ...... so on
}

public class CompanyInfo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    // [Key, ForeignKey("StockInfo")]
    public int CompanyInfoID { get; set; }
    public int avgVolume { get; set; }
    public string coName { get; set; }
    ...........
}

public class CorpAction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int corpActionType { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    ........

    public int StockInfo_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try to save/update `StockInfo` in my repository:

```
public void SaveStockInfo(StockInfo StockWeeklyInfo)
{
    var content = context.StockInformation.Where(x => x.companyInfo.symbol == StockWeeklyInfo.companyInfo.symbol).FirstOrDefault();

    if (content == null)
    {
        context.StockInformation.Add(StockWeeklyInfo);
    }
    else
    {
        context.StockInformation.Remove(content);
        context.Entry(content).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        context.StockInformation.Add(StockWeeklyInfo);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My problem is that when I remove `StockInfo` and add a new one. In SQL Server, I can see a new `StockInfo` entity instead of the old one.

But in the `CompanyInfo` table, Entity Framework just add another one and doesn't delete the previous.

What I am doing wrong? Interestingly, `CorpAction` works well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - your code first model looks odd. You have:

```
  [ForeignKey("StockInfoID")]
  public virtual CompanyInfo companyInfo { get; set; }
```

and

```
[ForeignKey("StockInfo_ID")]
public virtual List<CorpAction> corpActions { get; set; }
```

Are those navigations declared properly? I doubt it, that you CompanyInfo entity has the same Id as StockInfo.

You also expect CompanyInfo to be deleted when StockInfo is deleted. Was the foreign key declared as "ON DELETE CASCADE"?